# Image color in UIButton gets masked to background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a `UIButton`, which should have a white image and a blue background. The problem is, that the color of the image gets masked by the background color and becomes white blue.
 [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyoWM.png) is how it should look like and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iM7eg.png) is what I get (ignore the difference in the background color). Here's the code where I set the image:

```
- (UIButton *)navButton
{
    if (_navButton == nil) {

        UIButton *navButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        navButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [navButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor appBlue]];
        [navButton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"car_icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [navButton setEnabled:NO];

        _navButton = navButton;
    }
    return _navButton;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use this**

```
      UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"car_icon"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
     [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Actually, I had to set the mode to `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal` to get it to work properly, but now it's perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Just set Background image instead of image of button

```
[navButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor appBlue]];
[navButton setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"car_icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[navButton setEnabled:NO];
```

Hope this will help you to solve this problem.